# $f^2 - Dg^2 \ = \ 1 \quad \text{ with } \quad f, g \in K[X]$ not solvable?

Tags: polynomials, diophantine-equations

could you help me with the following assignment?

---

Let $K$ be a field with characteristic $0$ and $D \in K[X] \setminus K$.
We write $rad(f)$ for the radical of a polynomial, the product of all monic irreducible polynomials dividing $f$. Then
$$
f^2 - Dg^2 \ = \ 1 \quad \text{ with } \quad f, g \in K[X] 
\quad \text{ and } \quad g \neq 0 
$$
Can't be solved if $\quad \deg(D) \ > \ 2 \deg(rad(D)) -2\quad $

---

*My own thoughts*

First I rewrote the equality: $(f-1)(f+1) \ = \ Dg^2$. If $h|f-1$ and $h|f+1$, then $h|(f+1)-(f-1)$, so $h$ is a unit, and since the radical is monic, we know that $rad((f-1)(f+1)) \ = \ rad(f-1)rad(f+1)$. So the equality we get is:
$$
rad(f-1) \cdot rad(f+1) \quad = \quad rad(Dg^2) 
$$ 
And this is where I got stuck. Could you give me a hint?

Comment: I have a problem with $f(x)=x^2+1$, $g(x)=x$, and $D(x)=x^2+2$. ($K=\mathbb{Q}$, say). Then $rad(D)=D$, $deg(D)=2$, hence the inequality is satisfied, but we have $f^2-Dg^2=1$.Perhaps verify your hypothesis (or maybe my example is wrong).

Comment: I have made I mistake, the $\geq$ had to be a $>$.

Comment: What is the radical of a polynomial?

Comment: I will add what I mean by that.

Answer (score 0):

I try a solution, but complicated, and of course to be verified. Also, I have supposed that your field $K$ is algebraically closed. For a polynomial $Q$, I note $d(Q)$ its degree.

A) First, let $P$ a non constant polynomial. Then we have the following inequality:
$$1+d(P)\leq d(rad(P-1))+d(rad(P+1))$$
To see why, put
$$P-1=c_1\prod_{a\in A_1}(x-a)^{n_a}\prod_{a\in A_2}(x-a)$$
Here $A_1$ is the set of multiple zeros of $P-1$, $n_a$ is the multiplicity of $a$ as a zero of $P-1$. The set $A_2$ is the set of simples zeros of $P-1$.

In the same way, we put
$$P+1=c_2\prod_{a\in B_1}(x-a)^{n_a}\prod_{a\in B_2}(x-a)$$

Now we have
$d(rad(P-1))=|A_1|+|A_2|$ and $d(rad(P+1))=|B_1|+|B_2|$.
Let $a\in A_1$. As $a$ is a multiple zero of $P-1$, we get that $P^{\prime}(a)=0$, and that $n_a=1+q_a$, where $q_a$ is the multiplicity of $a$ as zero of $P^{\prime}$.

We have hence:

$$d(P)=d(P-1)=\sum_{a\in A_1}(1+q_a)+|A_2|=|A_1|+|A_2|+\sum_{a\in A_1}q_a=d(rad(P-1))+\sum_{a\in A_1}q_a$$

We have also:

$$d(P)=d(P+1)=d(rad(P+1))+\sum_{a\in B_1}q_a$$

We add these two equalities (note that $A_1$ and $B_1$ are disjoints subsets of zeros of $P^{\prime}$):

$$2d(P)=d(rad(P-1))+d(rad(P+1))+\sum_{a\in A_1\cup B_1} q_a\leq d(rad(P-1))+d(rad(P+1))+d(P^{\prime})$$
and we are done.

B) Now suppose that there exists $f,g$ such that $f^2-Dg^2=1$. We note that $2d(f)=d(D)+2d(g)$, we start with your equality: $rad(f-1)rad(f+1)=rad(Dg^2)=rad(Dg)$, and we have:

$$2d(rad(f-1))+2d(rad(f+1))=2d(rad(Dg))\leq 2d(rad(D))+2deg(g)$$
Hence
$$ 2d(rad(f-1))+2d(rad(f+1))\leq 2d(rad(D))+2d(f)-d(D)$$
Now
$$d(D)\leq 2d(rad(D))-2(d(rad(f-1))+d(rad(f+1))-d(f))$$
If we apply A) to the polynomial $f$, we see that we have proved that

$$d(D)\leq 2d(rad(D))-2$$
and we are done.

Comment: I do not understand your question. Of course the reasoning you added is correct, I used it in part B). The part A) is only to prove a result used in part B).

Comment: Never mind, I made a mistake.

Comment: By A), we have $d(rad(f-1))+d(rad(f+1))-d(f)\geq 1$. In addition, I think that the general case can be proved in the following way: See if $rad(D)$ is independant from the base field $K$. If yes, the general case follows from the algebraically case.

Comment: By the way, how did you get the inequality just above "and we are done"?

Comment: @Koenraad van Duin: The answer is at the beginning of my last comment: I use A) for $f$: we have $d(rad(f-1))+d(rad(f+1))-d(f)\geq 1$

Comment: @Koenraad van Duin: if it is the first "and we are done" in part A), I use that $\sum_{a\in A_1\cup B_1} q_a$ is $\leq d(P^{\prime})\leq d(P)-1$, as $A_1$ and $B_1$ are disjoints.